# Print \cite{reference} as a personalised name

Tags: cross-referencing, natbib, links

I am trying to create a personalized reference as I found in some papers. I would like to do something like:

> some text (Author et. al 2001, hereafter A01)

where `A01` should be a link to the references as well as the link produced by `\cite{my-reference}`.

I am using the `natbib` package for the bibliography.

Any ideas?

Comment: With `natbib` you can define a "cite alias" for a reference. You could say `\defcitealias{my-reference}{A01}` and then use that alias with `\citepalias{my-reference}`/`\citetalias{my-reference}`. Unfortunately, this doesn't take care of the first "hereafter A01" citation automatically and you still need to remember to use a different citation command (`\citepalias`/`\citetalias` instead of `\citep`/`\citet`) whenever you cite such a reference with an alias.

Comment: Just my perspective as a reader: Ideally it should be (reasonably) clear which reference from the bibliography the shorthand "A01" refers to even without having to go back to find the first citation that introduces the usage. I'd find it quite annoying to always have to search for the first citation to be able to resolve the citation label (even more so in a longer document or in a document where it is natural to jump over sections). Generally style guides emphasise the importance of consistency, so I'd only use shorthands like this for a good reason.

Comment: `biblatex` has a slightly better `shorthand` support. You wouldn't have to use a different citation command for the alias/`shorthand`. `biblatex`'s `verbose` styles already have a "hereafter cited as" function built in that could also be translated to `authoryear` styles (with varying degrees of difficulty depending on the style and the exact output you expect with multiple citations and other edge cases).

Comment: @moewe thank you for your comments. Unfortunately, it's a common use in my working field to make aliases if you use often the same citation. Also, I'm using the `natbib`package because it is required from a specific journal.

Comment: Anyway, thank you. I solved the issue using your first comment.